# Visual Studio - "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I just installed **Visual Studio Community 2017** for school purposes. My lecturer gave us these [instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX6cX.png) to use a `GraphicsSDK` library with VS (after we have Visual Studio installed). I ran the `Tutorial.sln` file he gave but I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2oNx.png).

I have followed all the steps correctly. I've been looking at other questions on StackOverflow and they said to change the Properties/Output file to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)` but mine is correct.

I also noticed one line in the code which was underlined red.

```
/* Render here */
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It said that `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` was undefined. Not sure if this matters at all.

Comment: Have you made sure that the `Directories` bit in the solution settings has the right paths to the GraphicsSDK library files? So that it can find the library files and header files?

Comment: Also, you actual error you showed is simply because the compilation failed. Since it failed it did not build a executable. So it has no executable to run. Looking at the build output is what you need to do to see the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Visual Studio the folder settings were part of the IDE. But in version 2017 you specify the search paths in the application itself.

If you go to your projects properties you will see a **VC++ Directories** section:

[image: VC++ Directories]

You need to make sure that the folders to the libraries and include files are correct (for both debug and release configurations).

Then, when you do a build it will be able to find the definitions it needs. But your question is lacking a lot of information. This is my educated solution for now.